# Setting a fmemopen ed file descriptor to be the standard input for a child process

Tags: c, linux, pipe, mmap

I have an fmemopen file descriptor(pointing to a buffer in the parent) in Linux and I would like to be able to, in C, set this file descriptor as the standard input for a child process(for whom I do not have access to the code)

Is this possible?  If so how do I do it?  I would like to avoid having to write to disk if at all possible.

Comment: To clarify: You want to use mmap to write to an fd that's not actually connected to a real file?

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote the question I was using the wrong function, what I really want is an fmemopen file(ie a block of memory that can be used like a file).  I guess I could push it all out to standard out if necessary, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Inheriting stdin/out/err is based purely on file descriptors, not stdio FILE streams. Since `fmemopen` does not create a file descriptor, it cannot become a new process's stdin/out/err or be used for inter-process communication in any way. What you're looking for is a pipe, unless you need seeking, in which case you need a temporary file. The `tmpfile` function could be used to create one without having to worry about making a visible name in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can directly use your fd (if, then you would have do `dup2()`), but if not, you can create a `pipe()` where you feed your in-memory data and the client can receive it. Here as well, you probably would have to `dup2()` after `fork()`ing.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace file descriptor `0` by your mmaped file descriptor before forking:

```
int fd = ...;
dup2(fd, 0);
fork();
```

Comment: uhm.. it would be better to do this *after* forking