# Can I configure `stdin` to read from a c++ string?

Tags: c++, scanf, stdin

I have a lot of third party functions written in C which expect their input from `stdin` through `scanf()`. I have written others functions in C++ which call the c functions. Now, I am preparing the tests and I would like to write the input test cases in C++ strings.

So my question is whether there is a way of expressing that the `stdin` should read from a C++ string instead of the standard input? If I achieved that, then I could write several tests cases whose inputs are c++ strings, and my C++ functions, which call c functions expecting their input from `stdin`, would be transparently called.

Comment: Well, you could redirect the input from a file.

Comment: <s> `freopen`? First see how to make a file from a string... </s> No.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c). [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325873/redirect-stdout-to-a-variable-in-c).

Comment: If you can rewrite the C functions in C++, write them to accept an argument of type `std::istream &`.   There are various types of `istream`  (`ifstream` reads from a file, `istringstream` reads from a string, etc).  All you would need to do to test your functions is provide an instance of an appropriate type which has been initialised appropriately.   Generally speaking, C functions that read from `stdin` can't be coerced to read from a string in standard C++.

Comment: There is `c_str`. The second related link above only works for Linux (POSIX?) but that may be what you need.

Comment: You could use `std::cin` and `std::string`.  In C++, the `cin` is tied to the standard input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a fmemopen ed file descriptor to be the standard input for a child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316775/setting-a-fmemopen-ed-file-descriptor-to-be-the-standard-input-for-a-child-proce)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770964/is-it-possible-to-fake-a-file-stream-such-as-stdin-in-c](Is it possible to fake a file stream, such as stdin, in C?)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how portable this is, but at least with gcc-6.3 on Linux, you can reassign `stdin` to point to different stream, which scanf() will then use transparently as though it is still reading from the terminal. If you want to read from a pre-existing string, that new stream can be opened with something like [fmemopen()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html), which should be available on POSIX systems. This allows you to create a `FILE*` from a block of memory, such as the contents of a `std::string`.

As an illustration, the following code will `scanf()` five values from the string `"String with 3.14159 * 2"` as though they had been entered from the terminal:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ const std::string input("String with 3.14159 * 2");
  char s0[16], s1[16], s2[8];
  double pi = 3; 
  int two = -2;

  { FILE *old_stdin = stdin;
    FILE* strm = fmemopen((void*)input.c_str(), input.size(), "r");
    stdin = strm;

    scanf("%s %s %lf %s %d", s0, s1, &pi, s2, &two);
    std::cout << "s0=\"" << s0 << "\" s1=\"" << s1 << "\""
              << " pi=" << pi << " s2=\"" << s2 << "\""
              << " two=" << two << std::endl;

    stdin = old_stdin;
    fclose(strm);
  }

  scanf("%12s", s0);
  std::cout << "Stdin: \"" << s0 << "\"" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
s0="String" s1="with" pi=3.14159 s2="*" two=2
```

before returning `stdin` to its normal behaviour, where the second `scanf()` waits for input from the terminal.

It would be tempting to try a similar approach using `dup2()` (as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or)), but it appears that the file-descriptor returned by invoking `fileno()` on the value returned from `fmemopen()` is not valid (being -1 on my system).